# Gitlab: Avatar on linux is different from windows version

Tags: git, gitlab

I have one account on `Gitlab` but when I am on linux and push my changes to Gitlab it's avatar is different from when I push from windows. Like the picture bellow when I click the red avatar it goes to my Gitlab profile but when click on green avatar it shows `Microsoft Outlook2016`. I am on a project that sometime I use `linux` and sometimes `windows`.

What should I do to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Did you use the same name and email?

Comment: @Marcus yes they are same